# rsync --delete option not deleting in destination if deleted in source

Tags: command-line, rsync

i r-synced my itunes folder to my external USB hard drive (obviously no rsync server on the usb drive)

went perfect, however if i delete folder/file in source than perform rsync it does NOT delete from destination, if i add a folder/file it gets added to destination (as expected)

it must notice the deletion because in "stats" it will say 5348 files to be considered then i delete 1 and it says 5347 files to be considered...but does not delete on destination!

i have tried several diff paths configurations, and even diff delete options...but i cannot get to to delete

here is my script

***rsync -avhP --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r --delete --stats --exclude-from '/Users/iTunes/backup/exclude.txt' /Users/iTunes/Desktop/ /Volumes/itunes_BACK/***

please advise
thanks
jeoe

Answer (score 0):

See if there are any I/O errors listed in the output. (Maybe you will want to redirect the output to a file so you can grep through it for errors). I know that as a safety feature, rsync disables the deleting after it is finished if there were any I/O errors.

It would be helpful to see the output of running the command, but I understand if you feel you can't post that...